# Factory Design Pattern for alternating API Implementations?

Tags: php, api, singleton, factory-pattern, static-classes

I am currently working on a PHP Web Interface that allows for the management of hardware inventory. In my previous version, I implemented several API's (Monitoring Software/Billing Software/Deployment Software) but as they were the ones my company uses, I didn't have to worry about catering to variations.

When rewriting this, I have found that I want to cater to multiple of each type, such as 2 types of Billing Sofware, where the end user chooses which one they want to use. The methods should remain the same, however it will use a different API, different function code, etc. to obtain the same results.

I am looking at Static Classes, Factory Patterns, Singleton classes, Interfaces/Abstract Classes, but thus far I am lost as to which one would be best suited for such a task?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [strategy pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy) or the [template method pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method).

Edit: Voodoo417 asked me to explain how I would use a strategy within this context. To be clear, my suggestion was intended to point the OP into the direction of behavioral patterns as opposed to creational patterns.

Depending on the complexity of the Billing Software API's, the solution could be a combination of many different patterns.

Also, keep in mind, I'm working with a user story as opposed to a set of *actual* requirements.

First, I assume when the OP says

> The methods should remain the same, however it will use a different
>   API, different function code, etc. to obtain the same results.

what he is actually saying is that he wants to abstract out an algorithm (or some functionality) to client classes that adhere to a common interface. This sounds a lot like the strategy pattern with perhaps a couple adapters (depending on the API's).

I will make the following assumptions.

- The OP wants to have a single API for two different billing software API's.
- The two billing software API's have the same high level functionality but may do some things a bit differently.

Keep in mind, this is an incredibly oversimplified explanation whose purpose is to demonstrate using the strategy pattern.

```
<?php

class Invoice
{
    private $id;

    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}

interface InvoiceApiInterface 
{
    public function find($id);
    public function create(Invoice $invoice);
}

class InvoiceApi implements InvoiceApiInterface
{
    private $invoiceApi; 

    public function __construct($api) 
    {
        // Should probably have this logic in a factory or something
        if ($api instanceof QuickenApi) {
            $this->invoiceApi = new QuickenInvoiceApi($api);
        } elseif ($api instanceof BillingTrackApi) {
            $this->invoiceApi = new BillingTrackInvoiceApi($api);
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('Invalid api.');
        }
    }

    public function find($id) 
    {
        return $this->invoiceApi->find($id);
    }

    public function create(Invoice $invoice)
    {
        return $this->invoiceApi->create($invoice);
    }
}

class QuickenInvoiceApi implements InvoiceApiInterface 
{
    private $api;

    public function __construct(QuickenApi $api)
    {
        $this->api = $api;
    }

    public function find($id) 
    {
        return $this->api->getInvoice($id);
    }

    public function create(Invoice $invoice)
    {
        return $this->api->createNewInvoice($invoice);
    }
}

class BillingTrackInvoiceApi implements InvoiceApiInterface 
{
    private $api;

    public function __construct(BillingTrackApi $api)
    {
        $this->api = $api;
    }

    public function find($id) 
    {
        return $this->api->find($id);
    }

    public function create(Invoice $invoice)
    {
        return $this->api->save($invoice);
    }
}

// Existing API's 
class QuickenApi 
{
    public function getInvoice($id)
    {
        return 'I am a quicken invoice from the quicken API, with an ID of ' . $id;
    }

    public function createNewInvoice(Invoice $invoice)
    {
        return 'Successfully created a quicken invoice with an ID of ' . $invoice->getId();
    }
}

class BillingTrackApi
{
    public function find($id)
    {
        return 'I am a Billing Track invoice from the billing track API, with an ID of ' . $id;
    }

    public function save(Invoice $invoice)
    {
        return 'Successfully created a billing track invoice with an ID of ' . $invoice->getId();
    }
}

writeln('Testing Quicken Invoice API');

$quickenApi = new QuickenApi();
$quickenInvoiceApi = new InvoiceApi($quickenApi);

writeln('Test 1: Find a quicken invoice.');
writeln($quickenInvoiceApi->find('SOME-QUICKEN-ID'));

writeln('Test 2: Create a quicken invoice.');
$quickenInvoice = new Invoice('QUICK123');
writeln($quickenInvoiceApi->create($quickenInvoice));

writeln('Testing Billing Track Invoice API');

$billingTrackApi = new BillingTrackApi();
$billingTrackInvoiceApi = new InvoiceApi($billingTrackApi);

writeln('Test 1: Find a billing track invoice.');
writeln($billingTrackInvoiceApi->find('SOME-QUICKEN-ID'));

writeln('Test 2: Create a billing track invoice.');
$billingInvoice = new Invoice('BILLINGTRACK123');
writeln($billingTrackInvoiceApi->create($billingInvoice));

writeln('Test Over.');

function writeln($line_in) {
    echo $line_in."<br/>";
}
```

**The results of running this script**

```
Testing Quicken Invoice API
Test 1: Find a quicken invoice.
I am a quicken invoice from the quicken API, with an ID of SOME-QUICKEN-ID
Test 2: Create a quicken invoice.
Successfully created a quicken invoice with an ID of QUICK123
Testing Billing Track Invoice API
Test 1: Find a billing track invoice.
I am a Billing Track invoice from the billing track API, with an ID of SOME-QUICKEN-ID
Test 2: Create a billing track invoice.
Successfully created a billing track invoice with an ID of BILLINGTRACK123
Test Over.
```

Comment: can you explain how would you use Strategy in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you would have to create a generic interface to access whatever actual piece of software lay behind.

However, doing so is a classic case of genericity delusion. The methodology guys will flash you encouraging smiles with cute little examples, but in real cases there can be many unpleasant surprises.

Unless the two softwares are really sharing the same philosophy, you might end up writing more code to try to cope with the differences than you would making a specific version for each. Developing and testing such a beast can prove extremely difficult and time-consuming.

I would be tempted to question the global design instead of ploughing on with a potentially painful solution.

Why would a guy want to switch from one billing system to another dynamically in the first place? For a given customer company, surely there will be only one billing system running.

You could be better off writing a specific front-end for that customer's billing software, and limit the work on generic interfaces to the connection of the billing dataflow with the other modules.